# 'Transforming' a function $T(m,n)$ into $a(n)$ in an inductive proof

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recursion

I'm trying to perform an inductive proof for a homework question but am stuck at a scenario I've never encountered before.

I am trying to prove inductively that

$$ T(m,n) = (m + 1 + n)\cdot a(n) - n! $$

where

$$a(n) = \begin{cases} n(a(n - 1) + 1) &, n \geq 1 \\
                       0 &, n = 0\end{cases}$$

We already know the following identity:

$$T(m,n) = \begin{cases} n(T(m+1,n-1) + m + 1 + n) &, n > 1 \\
                         m + 1 &, n = 1\end{cases}$$

I have done the base case n = 1 pretty easily where they both evaluate to $m + 1$, but for the inductive step, I'm completely stuck. **How can I get $a(n)$ into my equation to get this inductive step to work?** The hardest part for me to understand is how to work with these recursive functions.

Thanks for any help. A complete answer is not necessary, but feel free to take liberties if you find the problem interesting.

Comment: Maybe first try finding a closed expression for $a$ and proving it by induction. I conjecture $a(n) = 2n(n-1)(n-2) + (n-1) + n$ for $n = 4$ and $2n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1) + n$ for $n = 5$. Hopefully, I didn't do any mistake and you see the pattern.

Comment: $$T(m,n)\to \frac{(-1)^{m-1} \left(\frac{e (-1)^{m+1} (-n)! \Gamma (n,1)}{(-m-n-1)!}+\frac{e (-1)^{m+2} (-n)! \Gamma (n,1)}{(-m-n)!}+\frac{e (-m-n)! \Gamma (m+n,1)}{(-m-n-1)!}-e \Gamma (m+n,1)\right)}{(-m-n+1)_{m-1}}+\frac{(-1)^{m-1} c_1(m+n)}{(-m-n+1)_{m-1}}$$

For $n > 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for all $k\le (n-1)$, $P(n):=\{T(m,n)=(m+1+n)a(n)-n!$, for all $m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is true.

> We prove $P(n)$. For $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $$T(m,n)=n(T(m+1,n-1)+m+1+n)
> \\= n(\ ((m+1)+1+(n-1))a(n-1)-(n-1)!+m+1+n\ )
> \\= n((m+1+n)a(n-1)-(n-1)!+m+1+n)
> \\= n((m+n+1)a(n-1)+(m+n+1))-n!
> \\= (m+n+1)a(n)-n!$$

Comment: That helps quite a bit, thanks! All I had to do was substitute $m+1$ and $m-1$ into the definition of $T(m,n)$